# Finding top twitter users?

Tags: twitter, ranking, popularity

There is a large number of sites like [Twitaholic](http://www.twitaholic.com) or [Twittergrader](http://www.twittergrader.com/top/users) that offer rankings of Twitter users depending on the number of followers, influence, etc. I haven't found much information, though, on how do they compute these rankings.

My guess is that they begin with a handful users and keep exploring the followers' graph, while periodically updating the information of the users they already know of.

So the question is: is this the right approach or is there a more trivial way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sites you mention started years ago, and at that time they were given whitelisting by Twitter, which means that they can make tens of thousands of API requests per hour. Twitter no longer gives out new whitelisted accounts, so this type of analysis cannot be done by new sites.  New accounts are only allowed to make 350 API requests per hour.

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact possible just to use the Twitter API to examine and remember everything about every user, which is what quite a few sites do. [twitter streaming api](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api)

Comment: I know about the APIs, but you still have to store and keep track of "all" users. I was hoping for a simpler alternative :)

Comment: You can maintain a random sampling of users, and examine each user they follow to a depth of one, and just sort that list by number of followers. This will probably give you the list of top followed users.